# Prove that $(a^\frac23 + b^\frac23)^\frac32 > (a^2 + b ^2)^\frac12$ for $a, b$ being positive real numbers.

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I'm working on an optimization problem in which to make my argument rigorous, I find myself needing to prove that $(a^\frac23 + b^\frac23)^\frac32 > (a^2 + b ^2)^\frac12$ for $a, b$ being positive real numbers. I've played around with it for around 3 hours already but couldn't seem to prove it. I hope someone could give me a hint as to how to approach it  (e.g. which identities to apply). A full proof is appreciated as well!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work? $$\left(a^{\frac{2}{3}} + b^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}} > \left(a^2+b^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \Longleftrightarrow \left(a^{\frac{2}{3}} + b^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)^{3} > \left(a^2+b^2\right) \Longleftrightarrow$$$$ a^2 + b^2 + 3(ab)^{\frac{2}{3}}\left(a^{\frac{2}{3}} + b^{\frac{2}{3}}\right) > a^2+b^2$$ which is true as $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^+$

Comment: I was indeed overthinking it. For some reason, I never thought about going backward to a true identity, something I just did a while ago for a different problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: @ten_to_tenth Welcome. BTW I am a new user of Stack Exchange, do you click the green tick button on an answer to verify that it is correct?

Comment: Yes, I just did! I had to wait for at least 5 minutes before accepting an answer after posting hehe! Thank you again!

Comment: @ten_to_tenth Welcome. I asked it because I had asked a question too but with no response.